# I I am trying to make a comment box, but my comment wont show before refresh and it gets posted again if you refresh another time

Tags: mysql, sql

Need my comment box to not post comments again when page is refreshed and my i like the comments to appear without the having to refresh the site.
              
                  
                  Lagt inn  av 
 
            
             Skriv ny kommentar: 
            ">
           **Navn:**
         
          **Kommentar:**

```
   /*if ($_POST["sendknapp"] == "Send")*/
    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST") /* sjekkar om form er sendt */
  {    
   //mysql_connect("localhost","root",""); /* server, username, passord */
   //mysql_select_db("mydb");   
   $db = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","mydb");  
   $navn=$_POST["navn"];  
   $tekst=$_POST["tekst"];    
   $query ="INSERT INTO kommentar (navn, tekst,innlegg_id)";    
   $query.=" VALUES ('$navn','$tekst','$id')";    
   $resultat=mysqli_query($db, $query);    
   if ($resultat) printf("Kommentar lagt inn med id %d\n",       mysqli_insert_id($db));    
   else printf("ikkje i stand til å senda query:%s", $query);;  


   } 
   ?>
```

Comment: You have a big security problem. It is called "SQL Injection". Read about it before you continue to work on your problem.

Answer (score 0):

It happens, because the form will resended. When comment insertation was ok, then you need to redirect a user to a page, maybe itself:

```
//Show message if there is $_GET["msg"];
if (!empty($_GET["msg"])) {
    echo $msg;
}
if ($resultat) {
    //printf("Kommentar lagt inn med id %d\n", mysqli_insert_id($db));
    //$url is where you want to redirect the user
    header("Location: " . $url . "?msg=Comment sent");
    die();
} else {
    echo 'Comment not sent';
}
```